# Is it possible to get which user triggered an event in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

Im learning how to use the analytics tool of firebase, i have the following problem:

[image]

I'd like to get who triggered those events, how would i got about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics for Firebase only collects anonymized data by default.  The console doesn't give you the identity of users who trigger events.

If you want per-user information, you're going to have to write client code to set a user property with the identifying piece of data (for example, a user ID), then [export Analytics data to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7030014?hl=en), and make queries from there.

Comment: Oh i see, i was going about firebase the wrong way then, i'll checkout bigquery, thank you a lot Doug!